# No setter/field for Detail found on class com.example.mayank.messaging.productDetail

Tags: java, android

Code to read data from firebase

```
        mChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {


                productDetail productdetails  = dataSnapshot.getValue(productDetail.class);
                 System.out.println("URL:"+ productdetails.getp_url());

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }

        };
    mMessageDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(mChildEventListener);
```

class productDetail

```
enter code here

package com.example.mayank.messaging;

/**
 * Created by mayank on 22/8/17.
 */

public class productDetail {
String p_id ;
String p_cost ;
String p_url ;
String p_name ;


public productDetail() {

}

public productDetail(String p_id, String p_name, String p_cost, String p_url)
{
  this.p_id = p_id ;
  this.p_name = p_name ;
    this.p_cost = p_cost ;
    this.p_url = p_url ;


}

public String getp_id(){
    return(p_id) ;

}
public void setp_id(String p_id){
    this.p_id = p_id ;
}

public String getp_name(){
    return(p_name);
}
public void setp_name(String p_name){
    this.p_name = p_name ;
}

public String getp_cost(){
    return(p_cost) ;

}
public void setp_cost(String p_cost){
    this.p_cost = p_cost ;
}

public String getp_url(){
    return(p_url) ;

}
public void setp_url(String p_url){
    this.p_url = p_url ;
}
```

}

Adapter class

```
enter code here

 package com.example.mayank.messaging;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.TextView;


  import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

  import java.util.List;

  /**
   * Created by mayank on 22/8/17.
  */

  public class PhotoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<productDetail> {

  public PhotoAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<productDetail> objects){
    super(context, resource, objects);
    }

@Override
public View getView(int position , View converView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(converView == null) {
        converView = ((Activity) getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.product_detail, parent, false);

    }

    ImageView photoImageView = (ImageView) converView.findViewById(R.id.photoImageView);
    TextView product_id = (TextView) converView.findViewById(R.id.pid) ;
    TextView product_name = (TextView) converView.findViewById(R.id.pname) ;
    TextView product_cost = (TextView) converView.findViewById(R.id.pcost) ;

    productDetail product = getItem(position);

          Glide.with(photoImageView.getContext()).load(product.getp_url()).into(photoImageView);
    product_id.setText(product.getp_id()) ;

    product_name.setText(product.getp_name()) ;
    product_cost.setText(product.getp_cost()) ;

    return converView ;
}
```

}

errors

```
08-25 11:20:18.778 3961-3961/com.example.mayank.messaging W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for Detail found on class com.example.mayank.messaging.productDetail
08-25 11:20:18.778 3961-3961/com.example.mayank.messaging W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for Primekeys found on class com.example.mayank.messaging.productDetail
08-25 11:20:18.778 3961-3961/com.example.mayank.messaging W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for Messages found on class com.example.mayank.messaging.productDetail
08-25 11:20:18.778 3961-3961/com.example.mayank.messaging I/System.out: URL:null
08
```

[firebase databse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2dyX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..!!! I think.....
There are no setter methods for Detail, Primekeys, Messages. 
Create them or change those you have there that represent this 3.
You will keep having this error because in your firebase database you have this fields and there are no methods that set them .....